# SQL Setting a number column to entries based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    AcountID        Name              Percent
    10010377        M. D. NIGH         60.00
    10010377        D. L. NIGH         40.00
    10010378        W. M. EDWARDS      33.30
    10010378        J. LANE            33.30
    10010378        D. MCCANN          33.30
    10010322        K. LANT            80.00
    10010322        P. MCAN            20.00
```

I have a table that contains owners for certain companies and their percentage.
Is there a way using sql to return a number of each entry based on the percentage.

What I want is to have something similar to the following output.

```
Number          AcountID        Name              Percent
10010377-1      10010377        M. D. NIGH         60.00
10010377-2      10010377        D. L. NIGH         40.00
10010378-1      10010378        W. M. EDWARDS      33.30
10010378-2      10010378        J. LANE            33.30
10010378-3      10010378        D. MCCANN          33.30
10010322-1      10010322        K. LANT            80.00
10010322-2      10010322        P. MCAN            20.00
```

Thanks.

Comment: So do you want a solution for MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER. It is quite simple here.

Comment: I prefer in SQL Server, but if its easier for you in MySQL I can manage to get the translation

Comment: @SeanLange I don't think it will work using row number.

Comment: Why would row number not work?

Comment: Does it take into the consideration the AccountID as well as the percentage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the values using ROW_NUMBER.

```
select AccountID
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by AccountID order by Percent desc) as RowNum
    , Name
    , Percent
from SomeTable
```

I will let you add the varchar cast to AccountID and ROW_NUMBER to get the exact output you want.